# Checking extra column laravel auth login

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-authorization

I have checked extra column named verified while logging in in addition to email and password. I made it changing in AuthenticatesUser.php like below
protected function credentials(Request $request)

```
{
    //return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $credentials = array_add($credentials, 'verified', '1');
    return $credentials;
}
```

It's working now. and I want to send error message not verified if email and password matches but verified=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UserController.php**

```
public function doLogin(){

        // validate the info, create rules for the inputs
        $rules = array(
            'email'    => 'required|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
            'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 6 characters
            );

        // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('user/login')
                ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
                ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
            } else {
            // create our user data for the authentication
                $userdata = array(
                    'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                    'password'  => Input::get('password')
                    );

            // attempt to do the login
                if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
                // validation successful!
                // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
                // check if verified
                    $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();
                    if ($user->confirmed==1) {
                        return Redirect::to('user/dashboard');
                    }
                    else{
                        Auth::logout(); 
                        return redirect('user/login')->with('flash_msg','Your account is not verified. Check your email for further process.')->withInput(Input::except('password'));
                    }
                } else {        
                // validation not successful, send back to form 
                    return redirect('user/login')->with('error_msg','Invalid login information, try again')->withInput(Input::except('password'));
                }
            }
        }
```